# Carrying mustard oil in checked luggage into Germany

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage, food-and-drink, prohibited-items

So I consume mustard oil a lot and this is very costly in Germany. I purchased a 5 liter (1.32 Gallon) bottle and put it in my checked baggage (the one that goes inside the plane hold, that's what I mean).

Will this be allowed? I am travelling from India to Frankfurt.

Comment: I am having a little trouble understanding the exact meaning of the construction "purchased [...] and put it in my checked baggage". Does this imply you already checked the baggage containing the bottle, or did you only purchase the bottle and *intend* to check it in your baggage? - This confusion may have made my answer lean too much towards customs instead of also including transport restrictions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you refer to "Mustard Oil", I assume the first of the definitions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustard_oil) is applicable: "A fatty vegetable oil resulting from pressing the seeds". This, in my personal opinion, is food.

On the [German *Zoll*'s website](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/restrictions_node.html) you can find the following information regarding "The private import of food and animal feed":

**"The import of food and animal feed for the consignee’s private use or consumption is permitted in principle."**

Following this there is a list of exceptions and restricted goods, none of which should apply to your case.

So, in my personal opinion, as far as you are allowed to bring it on board your plane, you should be permitted to take it into Germany!

Edit: On a side note, any food consisting of plants not completely processed may also be subject to the regualtions on plants. Especially (primarily probably raw) potatoes are never to be imported into Germany from outside the EU! - But oil seems to be well out of this category.

Comment: Great answer and citation, thanks :) Also, 5 liter is allowed in baggage?

Comment: I doubt that this answer is correct. Flammable liquids are prohibited, also in checked luggage, and most (if not all) vegetable oils have flammability properties similar to lamp oil, kerosene or diesel.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo You may be correct in respect to transporting oil in one's luggage. Even though my answer concentrates on whether it is allowed to bring the oil into Germany, because of that possibilityit contains the qualifier "as far as you are allowed to bring it on board". - I will clarify this further!

Answer (score 1):

I visited France last year, and the laws may be similar for France and Germany, both being EU countries. I knew mustard oil may be unavailable or expensive, and took 3 litres with me. I didn't face any problem, and I doubt 5 litres will be a hassle either. I flew with Qatar Airways, I don't know if the answer will depend on the carrier.

Comment: Did you declare it to the customs people and get permission to take it into the country or did you just walk through the 'nothing to declare' line?

Comment: I just walked through.

Comment: As you just walked through you do not know whether it was allowed. While I appreciate your willingness to help, I am going to down vote this answer as not useful.